# DataSnap Delphi XE3 and Android 4.0 not function return select?

Tags: java, android, delphi

I'm here with an error in version 4.0 of the android when use the webservice that I created in Delphi by datasnap, in version 2.0 of the android runs smoothly round, more in version 4.0 generates an exception, and not know why
**"javaandroid.DBXException"**

My select in Delphi

```
   function TServerMethods1.GetDados_Clientes(Codigo: string; out Nome: string): string;
    var
     sSQL: string;
     begin
        sSQL := ' SELECT CAST(CODIGO AS VARCHAR(30))AS CODIGO, NOME '+
           '   FROM CLIENTES '+
           '  WHERE ATIVO = ''Sim'' '+
           '  AND CAST(CODIGO AS VARCHAR(30)) = '+ QuotedStr(Codigo);  

        with CDS_Tabelas do
        begin
          Close;
          CommandText := sSQL;
          Open;
          Nome := FieldByName('CODIGO').AsString + ' - ' +  FieldByName('NOME').AsString;
          Result := Nome;
        end;
      end;
```

In the java proxy class that generates the embarcadero so this method

```
  public static class GetDados_ClientesReturns {
     public String Nome;
     public String returnValue;
  }

  public GetDados_ClientesReturns GetDados_Clientes(String Codigo)
        throws DBXException {
     DSRESTCommand cmd = getConnection().CreateCommand();
     cmd.setRequestType(DSHTTPRequestType.GET);
     cmd.setText("TServerMethods1.GetDados_Clientes");
     cmd.prepare(get_TServerMethods1_GetDados_Clientes_Metadata());
     cmd.getParameter(0).getValue().SetAsString(Codigo);
     getConnection().execute(cmd);
     GetDados_ClientesReturns ret = new GetDados_ClientesReturns();
     ret.Nome = cmd.getParameter(1).getValue().GetAsString();
     ret.returnValue = cmd.getParameter(2).getValue().GetAsString();
     return ret;
  }
```

I Spoke to use **AsyncTask.**, but I could not run the code

```
   public class BuscaCliente extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private Context context;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Cria novo um ProgressDialogo e exibe
        progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progress.setMessage("Aguarde...");
        progress.show();

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        DSRESTConnection conn = getConnection();
        TServerMethods1 serv = new TServerMethods1(conn);

        try {
            String idCharCodItem = edtCliente.getText().toString();
            String[] idNumItem = idCharCodItem.split("-");

            GetDados_ClientesReturns ret;
            ret = serv.GetDados_Clientes(idNumItem[0]);

            if (ret.Nome.equals(" - ")) {
                Alerta.mostrarAtencao(VendaClienteActivity.this,
                        getString(R.string.msg_clientenaolocalizado), 0,
                        false);
                carregando(false);
                // permanece no mesmo focus
                edtCliente.setText("");
                edtCliente.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                edtCliente.requestFocus();

            } else {
                // parametro = 0 significa 'Não', 1 significa 'Sim'
                if (parametroBLOQUEIA_CLIENTE_S_REG_ENTR() == 1) {
                    // ai verifica se o cliente tem registro do entrada
                    if (verificaIDCliente() != Integer
                            .parseInt(idNumItem[0])) {
                        Alerta.mostrarAtencao(
                                VendaClienteActivity.this,
                                getString(R.string.msg_clientesemregentrada),
                                0, false);
                        carregando(false);

                        // permanece no mesmo focus
                        edtCliente.setText("");
                        edtCliente.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        edtCliente.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        mudaFocusCliente();
                        // recebe o nome e o id do cliente
                        edtCliente.setText(ret.Nome);
                    }
                } else {
                    mudaFocusCliente();
                    // recebe o nome e o id do cliente
                    edtCliente.setText(ret.Nome);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(VendaClienteActivity.this, e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me do this?

Thank you.

---

Logcat

```
   01-12 07:54:38.139: D/AndroidRuntime(16712): Shutting down VM
   01-12 07:54:38.139: W/dalvikvm(16712): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught   exception (group=0x40018578)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712): java.lang.NullPointerException
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:141)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:63)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:80)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:76)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at  br.com.azsolucoes.azcomanda.activities.VendaClienteActivity$BuscaCliente.onPreExecute(Venda       ClienteActivity.java:2061)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at  android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at  br.com.azsolucoes.azcomanda.activities.VendaClienteActivity.setFocusEdit(VendaClienteActivi       ty.java:285)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at br.com.azsolucoes.azcomanda.activities.VendaClienteActivity$7.onClick(VendaClienteActivity.       java:1026)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at  android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at  android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
   01-12 07:54:38.139: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

I use the code in version 2.0 without **AsyncTask**

```
 private void pesquisarClientes() {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Aguarde...",
            "Pesquisando registros.", false, true);
    dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    DSRESTConnection conn = getConnection();
    TServerMethods1 serv = new TServerMethods1(conn);

    try {
        String idCharCodItem = edtCliente.getText().toString();
        String[] idNumItem = idCharCodItem.split("-");

        GetDados_ClientesReturns ret;
        ret = serv.GetDados_Clientes(idNumItem[0]);

        if (ret.Nome.equals(" - ")) {
            ShowMensagem.showMessage("Atenção!",
                    MensagensCentralizadas.msg_clientenaolocalizado, this);
            // permanece no mesmo focus
            edtCliente.setText("");
            edtCliente.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            edtCliente.requestFocus();

        } else {
            // parametro = 0 significa 'Não', 1 significa 'Sim'
            if (parametroBLOQUEIA_CLIENTE_S_REG_ENTR() == 1) {
                // ai verifica se o cliente tem registro do entrada
                if (verificaIDCliente() != Integer.parseInt(idNumItem[0])) {
                    ShowMensagem
                            .showMessage(
                                    "Atenção!",
                                    MensagensCentralizadas.msg_clientesemregentrada,
                                    this);
                    // permanece no mesmo focus
                    edtCliente.setText("");
                    edtCliente.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    edtCliente.requestFocus();
                } else {
                    mudaFocusCliente();
                    // recebe o nome e o id do cliente
                    edtCliente.setText(ret.Nome);
                }
            } else {
                mudaFocusCliente();
                // recebe o nome e o id do cliente
                edtCliente.setText(ret.Nome);
            }
        }

        finalizaDialogo(false, "");
        // desabilita o dialog
        dialog.dismiss();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // desabilita o dialog
        dialog.dismiss();
        finalizaDialogo(true, e.toString());
    }
}
```

---

I got here using this code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.getWindow().clearFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    setContentView(R.layout.tela_vendacli);

    // versão 4.0 android
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

thank you

Comment: do you have a stacktrace in logcat? please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement of his method

```
function TServerMethods1.GetDados_Clientes(Codigo: string; out Nome: string): string;
```

if the result is already the string does not need to use the out, if you can put as var, but not necessary.

```
function TServerMethods1.GetDados_Clientes(Codigo: string; var Nome: string): string;
```

regenerate the proxy and care that the result is not null or nil.

the proxy is not or can not mistake it, but he can not make a cast of a TJsonNull for TJsonObject.

Comment: All questions and answers on StackOverflow should be in English. This is simply to ensure that they are understandable to the widest possible audience. If your English is not that great, do your best, and other users can edit to improve the grammar/spelling etc.